# One way binding in angularjs 1.4

Tags: angularjs

According to [Exploring Angular 1.3: One time bindings](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html);

> Using new syntax is as easy as starting an expression with ::. So if we apply the one-time expression to our example above, we change this:
>
> ```
> <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
> ```
>
> To this
>
> ```
> <p>Hello {{::name}}!</p>
> ```
>
> and it is now one way binding.

But how can we create a one time binding when using angular directives such as ng-class? I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
ng-model="::name"
ng-class="['label',{'label-danger': 'High' == ::tsk.Priority}]:
```

Comment: downvoter's do u know the answer's to this question.
If yes plz comment then downvote..

Comment: The problem is with your title. You are asking about one-way data-binding, but from your example(and answer) it looks like you are looking for one-time binding. Two, significantly different things

Answer (score 12):

Got my answer here http://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/

```
{{ ::vm.user }}

<div ng-if="::vm.user.loggedIn"></div>

<div ng-class="::{ loggedIn: vm.user.loggedIn }"></div>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="user in ::vm.users"></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks to downvoters.