# How to change two way binding variable to one way binding variable in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a two way binding variable in my view and i need to make it as a one way binding. 
{{myMsg}}
I need to make it as  single binding. How could i achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One way binding in angularjs 1.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476821/one-way-binding-in-angularjs-1-4)

Comment: Do you want to allocate same value to two models?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it either using ng-bind directive or using 2 full colons in front of expression.
eg: {{::myMsg}} or using ng-bind="myMsg"